# Is it possible to prevent creating multiple locks for thasame file using fcntl.flock() python?

Tags: python, file-io, locks

I'm using fcntl.flock in python to lock files.
I warped the locking mechanism in class something like that:

```
class Locker:
    def __enter__ (self):
        self.fp = open("./lockfile.lck")
        fcntl.flock(self.fp.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_EX)

    def __exit__ (self, _type, value, tb):
        fcntl.flock(self.fp.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_UN)
        self.fp.close()
```

my problem is that I run the process from different file and import the class and it creates me 2 different locks for this file....
How can I solve that? might be it because I'm creating
open("./lockfile.lck")???
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want separate process to use the same lock, they must use the *same* file as a lock. A relative path like ``./lockfile.lck`` will result in *separate* lock files for each working directory. Use an absolute path, or at least a well-defined path (e.g. rooted at the home directory) instead.

Comment: It still does not work for me :(